# CharSequence VS String in Java?

Tags: java, string, charsequence

Programming in Android, most of the text values are expected in `CharSequence`.

Why is that? What is the benefit, and what are the main impacts of using `CharSequence` over `String`?

What are the main differences, and what issues are expected, while using them, and converting from one to another?

Comment: Better answers can be found at [Exact difference between CharSequence and String in java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11323962/3681880)

Answer (score 364, accepted):

[Strings are CharSequences](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), so you can just use Strings and not worry. Android is merely trying to be helpful by allowing you to also specify other CharSequence objects, like StringBuffers.

Comment: Except when Android passes me a CharSequence in a callback and I need a String - call charSeq.toString().

Comment: But keep in mind this caveat from the `CharSequence` javadoc: This interface does not refine the general contracts of the `equals` and `hashCode` methods. The result of comparing two objects that implement `CharSequence` is therefore, in general, **undefined**. Each object may be implemented by a different class, and there is no guarantee that each class will be capable of testing its instances for equality with those of the other. It is therefore inappropriate to use arbitrary `CharSequence` instances as elements in a set or as keys in a map.

Comment: @TrevorRobinson, So isn't that a design bug?

Comment: @Pacerier: I think it's more of a practical limitation. `CharSequence` was a retrofit in JDK 1.4 to introduce a limited-purpose common interface to objects containing character sequences. Some of those objects contain other state, so it may not make sense to define `Object.equals` as "contains the same character sequence". NIO `CharBuffer`, for instance, only exposes the characters between its `position` and `limit` as the `CharSequence`, despite potentially holding many other characters.

Comment: @TrevorRobinson, So the design bug is having `equals`/`hashCode` on `Object` in the first place....

Comment: @Pacerier: IMHO There isn't a design bug in either `Object` or `CharSequence`, no interface is required to provide equality sanity between implementations. No two `Collection`s are required to provide equality between the `Collection` interface, but they can if they choose to. IMHO `CharSequence` should be limited to inputs and used less for return types.

Comment: @Pacerier, yes.

Comment: And I was trying to equate CharSequence == String in kotlin , the compiler does not give me any error but at runtime, some times it used to work fine but some times, even when the values are same, the condition equated to false. This was really strange until, I realized one of them is CharSequence and not String.

Answer (score 97):

## `CharSequence` = interface 
`String` = concrete implementation

- [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html) is an [interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(Java)).
- Several classes [implement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(Java)#Implementing_interfaces_in_a_class) this interface.

  - [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) is one such class, a concrete implementation of `CharSequence`.

You said:

> converting from one to another

There is no converting from `String`.

- Every `String` object *is* a `CharSequence`.
- Every `CharSequence` can produce a `String`. Call [`CharSequence::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html#toString()). If the `CharSequence` happens to be a `String`, then the method returns a reference to its own object.

In other words, every `String` is a `CharSequence`, but not every `CharSequence` is a `String`.

### Programming to an interface

> Programming in Android, most of the text values are expected in CharSequence.
>
> Why is that? What is the benefit, and what are the main impacts of using CharSequence over String?

Generally, programming to an interface is better than programming to concrete classes. This yields flexibility, so we can switch between concrete implementations of a particular interface without breaking other code.

When developing an [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) to be used by various programmers in various situations, write your code to give and take the most general interfaces possible. This gives the calling programmer the freedom to use various implementations of that interface, whichever implementation is best for their particular context.

For example, look at the [Java Collections Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework). If your API gives or takes an ordered collection of objects, declare your methods as using `List` rather than `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, or any other 3rd-party implementation of `List`.

When writing a quick-and-dirty little method to be used only by your code in one specific place, as opposed to writing an API to be used in multiple places, you need not bother with using the more general interface rather than a specific concrete class. But even then, it does to hurt to use the most general interface you can.

> What are the main differences, and what issues are expected, while using them,

- With a `String` you know you have a single piece of text, entirely in memory, and is immutable.
- With a `CharSequence`, you do not know what the particular features of the concrete implementation might be.

The `CharSequence` object might represent an enormous chunk of text, and therefore has memory implications. Or may be many chunks of text tracked separately that will need to be stitched together when you call `toString`, and therefore has performance issues. The implementation may even be retrieving text from a remote service, and therefore has latency implications.

> and converting from one to another?

You generally won't be converting back and forth. A `String` *is* a `CharSequence`. If your method declares that it takes a `CharSequence`, the calling programmer may pass a `String` object, or may pass something else such as a `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`. Your method's code will simply use whatever is passed, calling any of the `CharSequence` methods.

The closest you would get to converting is if your code receives a `CharSequence` and you know you need a `String`. Perhaps your are interfacing with old code written to `String` class rather than written to the `CharSequence` interface. Or perhaps your code will work intensively with the text, such as looping repeatedly or otherwise analyzing. In that case, you want to take any possible performance hit only once, so you call `toString` up front. Then proceed with your work using what you know to be a single piece of text entirely in memory.

## Twisted history

Note the comments made on the [accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1049244/642706). The `CharSequence` interface was retrofitted onto existing class structures, so there are some important subtleties (`equals()` & `hashCode()`). Notice the various versions of Java (1, 2, 4 & 5) tagged on the classes/interfaces—quite a bit of churn over the years. Ideally `CharSequence` would have been in place from the beginning, but such is life.

My class diagram below may help you see the big picture of string types in Java 7/8. I'm not sure if all of these are present in Android, but the overall context may still prove useful to you.

[image: diagram of various string-related classes and interfaces]

Comment: Did you make this diagram yourself? wondering if there is a catalogue of these diagrams for different data structures.

Comment: @user171943 Authored by me, hand-crafted using [*OmniGraffle*](https://www.omnigroup.com/omnigraffle) app from the OmniGroup.

Answer (score 40):

I believe it is best to use CharSequence. The reason is that String implements CharSequence, therefore you can pass a String into a CharSequence, HOWEVER you cannot pass a CharSequence into a String, as CharSequence doesn't not implement String. ALSO, in Android the `EditText.getText()` method returns an Editable, which also implements CharSequence and can be passed easily into one, while not easily into a String. CharSequence handles all!

Comment: You can do `charSequence.toString()`

Comment: @jorge: Except that will be relatively inefficient if the sequence is mutable (or for any reason requires a copy of the characters in order to make in immutable string).

Answer (score 23):

In general using an interface allows you to vary the implementation with minimal collateral damage. Although java.lang.String are super popular it may be possible that in certain contexts one may want to use another implementation. By building the API around CharSequences rather than Strings the code gives one the opportunity to do that.

Answer (score 10):

An issue that DO arise in practical Android code is that comparing them with CharSequence.equals is valid but does not necessarily work as intended.

```
EditText t = (EditText )getView(R.id.myEditText); // Contains "OK"
Boolean isFalse = t.getText().equals("OK"); // will always return false.
```

Comparison should be made by

```
("OK").contentEquals(t.GetText());
```

Answer (score 8):

### CharSequence

A [`CharSequence`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html) is an interface, not an actual class. An interface is just a set of rules (methods) that a class must contain if it implements the interface. In Android a `CharSequence` is an umbrella for various types of text strings. Here are some of the common ones:

- [`String`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html) (immutable text with no styling spans)
- [`StringBuilder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) (mutable text with no styling spans)
- [`SpannableString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) (immutable text with styling spans)
- [`SpannableStringBuilder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html) (mutable text with styling spans)

*(You can read more about the differences between these [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41935087/3681880).)*

If you have a `CharSequence` object, then it is actually an object of one of the classes that implement `CharSequence`. For example:

```
CharSequence myString = "hello";
CharSequence mySpannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
```

The benefit of having a general umbrella type like `CharSequence` is that you can handle multiple types with a single method. For example, if I have a method that takes a `CharSequence` as a parameter, I could pass in a `String` or a `SpannableStringBuilder` and it would handle either one.

```
public int getLength(CharSequence text) {
    return text.length();
}
```

### String

You could say that a [`String`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html) is just one kind of `CharSequence`. However, unlike `CharSequence`, it is an actual class, so you can make objects from it. So you could do this:

```
String myString = new String();
```

but you can't do this:

```
CharSequence myCharSequence = new CharSequence(); // error: 'CharSequence is abstract; cannot be instantiated
```

Since `CharSequence` is just a list of rules that `String` conforms to, you could do this:

```
CharSequence myString = new String();
```

That means that any time a method asks for a `CharSequence`, it is fine to give it a `String`.

```
String myString = "hello";
getLength(myString); // OK

// ...

public int getLength(CharSequence text) {
    return text.length();
}
```

However, the opposite is not true. If the method takes a `String` parameter, you can't pass it something that is only generally known to be a `CharSequence`, because it might actually be a `SpannableString` or some other kind of `CharSequence`.

```
CharSequence myString = "hello";
getLength(myString); // error

// ...

public int getLength(String text) {
    return text.length();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is almost certainly performance reasons. For example, imagine a parser that goes through a 500k ByteBuffer containing strings.

There are 3 approaches to returning the string content:

1. Build a String[] at parse time, one character at a time. This will take a noticeable amount of time. We can use == instead of .equals to compare cached references.
2. Build an int[] with offsets at parse time, then dynamically build String when a get() happens. Each String will be a new object, so no caching returned values and using ==
3. Build a CharSequence[] at parse time. Since no new data is stored (other than offsets into the byte buffer), the parsing is much lower that #1. At get time, we don't need to build a String, so get performance is equal to #1 (much better than #2), as we're only returning a reference to an existing object.

In addition to the processing gains you get using CharSequence, you also reduce the memory footprint by not duplicating data. For example, if you have a buffer containing 3 paragraphs of text, and want to return either all 3 or a single paragraph, you need 4 Strings to represent this. Using CharSequence you only need 1 buffer with the data, and 4 instances of a CharSequence implementation that tracks the start and length.

Comment: references plz. sounds like randomly guessing what's going on. also i don't find your argument valid. one might simply store the 500k bytebuffer as a string in the first place and just return substrings, which is crazy fast, and much more common.

Comment: @kritzikratzi - as of JDK7, substring on String no longer shares the underlying array, and is not "crazy fast".  It takes O(N) time in the length of the substring, and generates a copy of the underlying characters each time you call it (so a lot of garbage).

Comment: @kritzikratzi I believe the reason for the change is that, if the copy were not made, the original String would be retained for the lifetime of all substrings. Given that substrings are usually only small parts of the original and could last indefinitely depending on how they are used, this would often result in even more garbage if the substrings were in use for a lot longer than the original string. An interesting alt might be to determine whether or not to copy based on the ratio of substring to parent string size, but you'd have to roll your own `CharSequence` implementation for that.

Comment: Perhaps I've missed the point, but this Answer is nonsense. A **[`CharSequence`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html) is an *interface*** – by definition, it has none of the implementation details you discuss because **it has no implementation** of its own. A `String` is one of several *concrete* classes that implements `CharSequence` interface. So a `String` *is* a `CharSequence`. You could compare performance details of `String` vs `StringBuffer` vs `StringBuilder`, but not `CharSequence`. Writing “processing gains you get using CharSequence” is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

`CharSequence` is an interface and `String` implements it. You can instantiate a `String` but you could not do that for `CharSequence` since it is an interface. You can find other implementations in `CharSequence` in the official Java website.

Answer (score -5):

CharSequence is a readable sequence of char values which implements String. it has 4 methods

1. charAt(int index)
2. length()
3. subSequence(int start, int end)
4. toString()

Please refer documentation [CharSequence documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html)

Comment: `CharSequence` does not implement `String`. The converse is true, though.

Comment: Please remove this nonsense answer