# What is the difference between CharSequence[] and a String[]?

Tags: java

What is the difference between `CharSequence[]` and `String[]`?

Comment: You might want to add a java tag. Or someone with enough rep can do it.

Comment: See _Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces_. `String` is a `class`, `CharSequence` is an `interface` (that `String` and a few others implement). `CharSequence[]` is more flexible. That said, _Item 25: Prefer lists to arrays_.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CharSequence VS String in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049228/charsequence-vs-string-in-java)

Answer (score 81):

[String](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) implements the [CharSequence](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) interface. CharSequence is implemented by String, but also CharBuffer, Segment, StringBuffer, StringBuilder.

So a String[] and a CharSequence[] is essentially the same. But CharSequence is the abstraction, and String is the implementation.

By the way, '[]' denotes an *array* of objects. So `String[]` is an array of strings. And String itself is an array of characters.

Comment: In Java String is not exactly an array of characters. The characters are stored in an array, but you never get access to ensure String is immutable.

Answer (score 32):

`CharSequence` represents an interface to a sequence of characters, with operations common to all classes implementing it. However, in particular, `CharSequence` does not make any guarantees about whether the sequence is mutable or not. So, you can have an immutable implementing class, like `String` or mutable ones, like `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer`.

In addition, `CharSequence` does not refine the general purpose implementations of the `equals()` or `hashCode()` methods, so there is no guarantee that objects of different classes implementing `CharSequence` will compare to be equal even if the underlying sequence that they hold is the same. So, given:

```
String seq1 = "hello";
StringBuilder seq2 = new StringBuilder("hello");
StringBuffer seq3 = new StringBuffer("hello");
```

comparisons between these three using `.equals()` return `false` on Java 1.6, but I can't find any guarantees that this will not change in the future (though it's probably fairly unlikely).

And `CharSequence[]` and `String[]` are just arrays of their respective types.

**EDIT**: The practical upshot of this is to compare `CharSequence`s for equality, you have to use their `toString()` method and compare the resultant `String`s, since this is guaranteed to return `true` if the underlying sequences are the same.

Answer (score 8):

A CharSequence is an Interface. String is an immutable sequence of characters and implements the CharSequence interface. CharSequence[] and String[] are just arrays of CharSequence and String respectively.

This means wherever you see CharSequence, you can pass a String object.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my diagram showing how [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is a one of several [concrete classes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)) implementing the [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) [interface](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_(object-oriented_programming)).

In particular, [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is commonly used as a faster alternative to concatenation `String` objects with the `+` operator, where thread-safety is not needed.

[image]

The square brackets means an array. So, `String[]` is an array of `String` objects, and `CharSequence[]` is an array of objects that may or may not be `String` objects but definitely are objects implementing the `CharSequence` interface.

See [my Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26498954/642706) and [my Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31169001/642706) for much more discussion.

Answer (score 1):

CharSequence is an interface. String is a class that implements the CharSequence interface. That means a String object passes as a CharSequence object. There are different classes that implement the CharSequence interface. They all define the methods that correlate with the method signatures (or abstract methods?) that the interface CharSequence provides.

Answer (score 1):

String is the parent class that implements the interface `CharSequence`.

There are other classes which also implement the `CharSequence` like `StringBuffer`, `StringBuilder`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**CharSequence** represents an ordered set of characters, and defines methods for examining this character set. It is ineterface, and one implementation of this interface is **String** class.

Please refer to Java API documentation for further info. Also, this tutorial might help you: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: An "ordered set of characters" would imply that the same character cannot occur twice.

Comment: I think his comment is meant to be case-sensitive. He didn't say 'Set', did he?