# why charsequence, instead of string?

Tags: android

while looking at the description of the method:

```
setMultiChoiceItems(CharSequence[] items, boolean[] checkedItems, DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener listener) ,
```

i was thinking that why can't we use an array of "string" type as a first argument of the method. Because acc. to the description of the method, charsequence[]= the text of the items to be displayed in the list. So, can't we use here a string array?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3600635)'s the actual dup: What is the difference between CharSequence[] and a String[]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you *can* use a `String[]` here, too.

CharSequence is an interface that String implements.