# StringBuffer vs StringBuilder Vs StringTokenizer

Tags: java

what is the difference between the StringBuffer vs StringBuilder Vs StringTokenizer on the internal implementation. when to use these . kindly waiting for the answer.

## Update:-

I am also going through the source code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between StringBuilder and StringBuffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/difference-between-stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer)

Comment: See [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31169001/642706) of mine for a nifty diagram I made as an overview of the string-related classes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`StringBuffer` - introduced in JDK 1.0 - is thread safe (all of its methods are `synchronized`), while `StringBuilder` - since JDK 1.5 - is not. Thus it is recommended to use the latter under normal circumstances.

`StringTokenizer` is meant for a whole different purpose then the former two: cutting strings into pieces, rather than assembling. As @Henning noted, it is also "retired" since JDK 1.5 - it is recommended to use `String.split` instead.

Comment: `StringTokenizer`, while not deprecated, is also a "legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code". http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: @Henning, thanks for noting - I updated my answer to include this.

Answer (score 9):

- StringBuffer is designed to be thread-safe and all public methods in StringBuffer are synchronized. StringBuilder does not handle thread-safety issue and none of its methods is synchronized.
- StringBuilder has better performance than StringBuffer under most circumstances.
- Use the new StringBuilder wherever possible.

[Here](http://littletutorials.com/2008/07/16/stringbuffer-vs-stringbuilder-performance-comparison/)  is `performance comparison`  of [StringBuilder & StringBuffer](http://littletutorials.com/2008/07/16/stringbuffer-vs-stringbuilder-performance-comparison/)

StringBuilder & StringBuffer Holds String where StringoTokeizer  class allows an application to break a string into tokens .. So It is like odd one out

Answer (score 4):

StringBuffer - is synchronized version of StringBuilder (introduced after its unsynchronized peer)

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler and clearer to say "StringBuilder is the non-synchronized version of StringBuffer"?

Comment: I am working a lot in java prior 1.5 where there was no StringBuilder, so my reference point is StringBuffer :-)

Comment: @Peter Török: No. It is perfectly simple and clear the way it is, and also gives a historical perspective, which yours doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

StringBuffer serves same purpose as StringBuilder except that StringBuffer is thread-safe.
 StringTokenizer is used for splitting the string into tokens based on some delimiters.