# How to cut off all the white spaces from String?

Tags: java

I have String containing zeros, ones and unfortunately a lot of white spaces. I want to write method which will get rid of all the white spaces and return String with just ones and zeros.

How can I do that?

```
String example= new String("1 011 01   1");

String shouldReturnStringWithoutWhiteSpaces(String given){
    String cleanString
    //some action which will "transform "1 011 01   1" into "1011011"
    return cleanString;
}
```

Comment: yes, it is. Just report as duplicate

Comment: @Leonardo - done and done. Still pretty green on SO so I didn't even think about it.

Comment: No problem ! Living and learning haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
String cleanString = given.replaceAll("\\s", "");
```

This will replace all whitespace with nothing.  The main trick is the `\\s` which becomes `\s` at runtime which means all white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Scanner` on your string with default delimiter. Add anything you find to a new string

```
string result = "";

Scanner scan = new Scanner(example);

while(scan.hasNext())
    result += scan.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that

```
 String res = given.replace(" ", "");
```

or

```
String res = given.replaceAll("\\s", "");
```

First one is `replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement;)`

Second one is `replaceAll(String regex, String replacement);`

More about differences between CharSequence and String is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049228/charsequence-vs-string-in-java). If you want yout function `String shouldReturnStringWithoutWhiteSpaces(String given)` to return String, you should use second one ;)

Answer (score -1):

String something = given.replaceAll(" +", "")

Comment: Why the downvote? Not sure how the regular expression works?