# How to add info from different locations in arrayList to a single string

Tags: java, arrays, string, return

I am trying to create a method which returns a single String (not String array) containing information for all objects in my array list. I know that strings are immutable so I am really struggling with how to add information from each object.

This is my method where I am trying to return a single string:

```
public String infoForEachItem ()
{
    String info;
    for (int y =0; y < items.size(); y++)
    {
        info = "ID: " + items.get(y).getId() + "\n" +
                "Name : " + items.get(y).getName() + "\n" +
                "Cost: " + items.get(y).getCost() + "\n";
        return info;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I want to create a string containing the Id, name, and cost of EACH item as a single string. It won't let me return within a for loop. Is there anyway to append something to the end of String?

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder` instead, use its `append` method to add to it and then *after* the loop return its content using its `toString` method.

Comment: We can use string concatenation, e.g `info += ...` (but `info` must be initialized beforehand, e.g. with `String info = "";`). We can also use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). --- A remark: we most probably do not want the `return` where it is right now.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I totally forgot about StringBuilder

Comment: See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31169001/642706) to a similar question, to see a diagram I made as an overview of the various textual data types in Java: `String`, `StringBuilder`, `StringBuffer`, `CharSequence`, and more.

Answer (score 2):

## `StringBuilder`

Use [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to build up text by appending multiple times.

Here is some code expanding on [comment by Federico klez Culloca](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72018996/how-to-add-info-from-different-locations-in-arraylist-to-a-single-string#comment127255766_72018996):

```java
public String infoForEachItem ()
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (Item item : items) {
        result.append("ID: ").append(item.getId()).append('\n');
        result.append("Name: ").append(item.getName()).append('\n');
        result.append("Cost: ").append(item.getCost()).append("\n\n");
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

You can chain the calls to [`.append`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(java.lang.String)) as you think it is suitable, and there are overloads of the method for many parameter types.